# Ajax call - ready state flow confusion

Tags: javascript, ajax, control-flow

I was developing using Ajax call and while debugging, I found Ajax is sending request/response so many time than I actually imagined.

Long time ago I got good document describing what's happening behind the scene but I lost it.

Nowadays Ajax tutorials on the web only talks about how to code and those IF statement only checks `readystate == 4` and `status == 200` which does not provide good explanation for someone like me.

I tested the flow with code below and output is I think weird. My confusion is why ready 4 state is showing up twice? According to the definition, **ready 4** means **completed** so there should be no reason to complete twice?

**OUTPUT**

```
START
ready 1                //loading
START
ready 2                //loaded
ready 2 status=200     //loaded
START
ready 3                //interactive
ready 3 status=200     //interactive
START
ready 4                //complete
START
ready 4                //complete   ... again???
```

**TEST CODE snippet**

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {    
    alert("START");

    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 0) {
        alert('ready 0');
        alert('ready 0 status=' + xmlHttp.status);
    }

    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 1) {
        alert('ready 1');
        alert('ready 1 status=' + xmlHttp.status);
    }

    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 2) {
        alert('ready 2');
        alert('ready 2 status=' + xmlHttp.status);
    }

    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 3) {
        alert('ready 3');
        alert('ready 3 status=' + xmlHttp.status);
    }

    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
        alert('ready 4');
    } 
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read in [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/09/xmlhttp_notes_r_2.html) about the way different browsers behave with AJAX calls and readyState.

I found [this](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.xml/browse_thread/thread/74257e17b66e68e8/8e0b8aded9bac4a0) link that claims using the `Abort` command will issue a readystate 4 (have not tested it) - are you using `Abort`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, nope I don't think I'm using abort. though I must search more about ajax behavior